# Transparent colored strip on left side of laptop monitor

Tags: laptop, display, hardware-failure, hp-envy

[image: Laptop Screen Image]

A solid, transparent strip has appeared on the left side of my laptop's monitor's screen. I am not sure of the cause. It seems to fade-in when the laptop initially starts. However, it also appears in bios

Comment: Have seen an issue like this before, the laptop did this because it was overheating.

Answer (score 1):

Plug in an external Monitor. If the strip does NOT appear on the External Monitor, and since the strip appears in BIOS and operating system, then you have a screen issue if the external display works. If the external display does NOT work, that would indicate a circuit on the board or GPU to be not working

Answer (score 0):

John's test will narrow down whether it is graphics card or screen failure, but if you don't have a second monitor to test you can do similar by taking a screen snap.

Move the snap or resize it so it doesn't fall on the same area of the screen - if it shows the stripe, then it's your graphics card. If there is no stripe [which is what I suspect] then your screen or the connector cable is damaged.